# Posible error en mi programa

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo unas matrices en lenguaje C, y el programa no me detecta los printf i esta dentro del main, alguien puede ayudarme a resolver el pequeño problema? Seguro que es un fallo tonto. Gracias. Es un ejercicio de hacer el método de pivotaje de gauss, el procedimiento lo entiendo pero no se porque no compila bien, soy nuevo programando y será un error tonto de novato.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda si no es molestia dado que también necesito mejorar en programación, aparte de posibles errores en el método de gauss.

```
float a[10][10]={0}, filamemoria[10],piv=0.000;
int i,j,k,l,o,p,s,indice=0,indicacion=0,columna=0,renglones=0;
int m=0;
int n=0;
int true;

int main()

{
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Eliminación de gauss-Joprdan\n Ingrese el tamanyo de filas\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        printf("Ingrese el tamanyo de columnas\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        
        for(i=0; i<m; i++) //podria estar mal
        {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                printf("Ingrese el valor de la Fila %d Columna %d\n", i+1, j+1);
                scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("  'Matriz original'  \n\n");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                printf("%.2f     ", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
        printf("\n\n\n");
        
        indicacion=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=indicacion;j<m;j++);
            {
                if(fabs (a[j][i])>0)
                {
                    indice=j;
                    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                    {
                    filamemoria[k]=(a[indicacion][k]);
                    a[indicacion][k]=(a[indice][k]);
                    a[indice][k]=filamemoria[k];    
                    }
                    indicacion++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(j!=renglones)
            {
                piv=a[j][i];
                for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                {a[j][k]=a[j][k]-(a[renglones][k]*piv);
                }
            }
        }
        renglones++;
        indicacion=0;
        for(l=0;l<n;l++)
        {
            for(o=indicacion;o<m;o++);
            {
                indice=o;
                for(p=0;p<n;p++)
                {
                    filamemoria[p]=(a[indicacion][p]);
                    a[indicacion][p]=(a[indicacion][p]);
                    a[indice][p]=filamemoria[p];
                }
                indicacion++;
            }
        }
        
    }
    

    printf("Matriz resultante\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f   ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("¿Desea relizar otra matriz? 1. Si 2.No \n");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    renglones=0;
    if(s==2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++);
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, dale formato a tu código y luego pon triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo. En una línea es muy complicado leerlo. Además, dale un título apropiado a tu pregunta, que dé una pista rápida de tu problema. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿por qué tienes `for(o=indicacion;o<m;o++);` ó `for(i=0;i<m;i++);`?

Comment: Ese `int true` es sospechoso...

Comment: Como te dice @padaleiana, ese `int true` da que pensar. Si quieres trabajar con variables de verdadero/falso trabaja con variables de tipo `bool` y luego le asignas el valor `true` o `false`. De todos modos, la variable de control de tu bucle `while` nunca cambia de valor, por lo tanto nunca saldrá de ese bucle y no se ejecutará la segunda parte de tu programa. (Puede salir también del bucle mediante la instrucción `break`)

Comment: "no se porque no compila bien" entonces, hay un error en tiempo de compilacion.. donde esta el error? aca fueron buenos, y leyeron todo tu codigo, pero si nos provees el error, seria muchisimo mas facil y rapido ayudarte.

Comment: @padaleiana es C, en C no existe el tipo `bool` y ni las palabras reservadas `true` o `false`. Otra cosa es que incluyese la librería `stdbool`, que no es que genere el tipo boolean y cree las palabras reservadas ... sino que crea un alias de un entero y define un par de macros (o tal vez constantes) para `true` y `false`. En cualquier caso es legal hacer `int true;` en C. Otra cuestión es si deberían evitarse ese tipo de prácticas

Answer (score 2):

> el programa no me detecta los printf

Eso es porque no has incluído las librerías que incorporan esas funciones

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Haces uso de funciones matemáticas `fabs`, por lo que también deberías incluir la librería matemática

```
#include <math.h>
```